Engine analysis graph
Is there chess applications that can create engine analysis graph?
Like the one lichess creates when you request engine analysis after a game.

What do you mean by graph? Like an evaluation graph per move? https://live.lczero.org/ can show W/D/L probabilities as well which is more useful for human games.

lucas chess will do that.
https://lucaschess.pythonanywhere.com
may be with more sophistication and extra information.
